# Problem with inner join

Tags: php, mysql

I have used inner join in my php page. Problem is when I fire query in mysql query browser it fetches nearly 6 rows. and all are correct but when I use same in my php page it fetch only one row. That is only one value..

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{   
while ($resultpoet = mysql_fetch_array($poet)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $iCounter?>
            . </td>
        <td><? if(($row['roman']=="")&&($row['hindi']=="")) { ?>
            <?=$row['name'] ?>
            <? } else { ?>
            <a href="sview.php?title=<?=$row['sid'] ?>">
            <?=$row['name'] ?>
            </a>
            <? } ?></td>
        <td width="216"><? 

 if($resultpoet['pstatus']!='u')
 print '<a href="pview.php?title='.$resultpoet['pname'].'">'.$resultpoet['pname'].'</a>';
else 
 print $resultpoet['pname'];

            ?>



            </td> 
        <td width="135"><?=$row['category'] ?></td>
        <td width="67"><a href="songtitle_action.php?title=<?=$row['sid'] ?>"> Edit </a>
            <input name="check[]" type="checkbox" value="<?=$row[s_id]?>" id="checkbox_<?=$row[sid]?>"></td>
        <td width="75"><?  if(($row['roman']=="")&&($row['hindi']=="")) { ?>
            <a href="song_add_lyrics.php?title=<?=$row['sid'] ?>"> Add Lyrics</a>
            <? } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <? }
            $iCounter++;
         }?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only calling `mysql_fetch_array` once, so you only get one row.

You need to instead iterate using `while` and do your output for each of the rows returned by the query.  This is a pretty simplistic example:

```
$poet= mysql_query("SELECT  p.name as pname, p.status as pstatus from poet p INNER JOIN song s ON p.pid=s.pid");
while ($resultpoet= mysql_fetch_array($poet)) {
   if($resultpoet['pstatus']=='u')
     print '<a href="pview.php?title='.$resultpoet['pname'].'">'.$resultpoet['pname'].'</a>';
   else 
     print $resultpoet['pname'];
}
```

Check out [the documentation for `mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), the example code elaborates on this principle.

Comment: Yes I forgot to do that... Correct that.. Have been puzzled since an hour.

Comment: As I am using this in a other while loop so each time outer while is fetch value it fetches all group of calue for that particular column or tuple. How to manage two while loops?

Comment: You can nest while loops all you'd like, just make sure you are using different variable names. :)

Comment: Edit your answer and include more code... don't get what you're talking about.

Comment: Still missing some code... put in the part where you are doing the queries.

Comment: @Aditii let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1672/discussion-between-chris-and-aditii)

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep calling `fetch_array`:

```
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($poet))
{
  /* do stuff with $result */
}
```